# Add space every time?

Tags: javascript

Currently I have a post repeater I created for personal use
It basically goes to the link and enters the text as well as a number that increases by 1 to get past the floodcheck on the forum.

I wish to make it so rather than posting a number next to the text, it instead posts a space increasing by 1 every time using a for loop before the variable Text
for example, say Text = Testing
" Testing"
"  Testing"
"   Testing"
And so on
This is my current code, please help, thanks.

```
var ID = prompt("ThreadID")
var Bump = prompt("Number of posts")
var Text = prompt("Text to repeat")
var Bumps = 0
var Page = "http://www.forum.com/forum.php?id=" + ID
function Go(){
$.get(Page,function(Data){
        var VS = Data.match(/id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.+)"/)[1]
        var EV = Data.match(/id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.+)"/)[1]
        $.post(Page,{
            "__VIEWSTATE" : VS,
            "__EVENTVALIDATION" : EV,
            "ctl00$cphRoblox$Createeditpost1$PostForm$PostBody" : Text+" "+Bumps,
            "ctl00$cphRoblox$Createeditpost1$PostForm$PostButton" : "Post"
        })
    })
}
Go()
var Times = setInterval(function(){
if (Bumps == Bump){
            clearInterval(Times)
    }
    Go()
    Bumps++
},40000)
```

Comment: sounds like a spam script, but to repeat a character: http://jsperf.com/repeating-character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go ahead and assume you have permission to be spamming whatever forum this is, so here goes.

I'm not sure if you want to add the spaces before or after `Text`, but this is for before:

```
var ID = prompt("ThreadID")
var Bump = prompt("Number of posts")
var Text = prompt("Text to repeat")
var whitespace_chars = '';
var Bumps = 0
var Page = "http://www.roblox.com/Forum/AddPost.aspx?mode=flat&PostID=" + ID
function Go(){    
    $.get(Page,function(Data){
            var VS = Data.match(/id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.+)"/)[1]
            var EV = Data.match(/id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.+)"/)[1]
            $.post(Page,{
                "__VIEWSTATE" : VS,
                "__EVENTVALIDATION" : EV,
                "ctl00$cphRoblox$Createeditpost1$PostForm$PostBody" : whitespace_chars + Text,
                "ctl00$cphRoblox$Createeditpost1$PostForm$PostButton" : "Post"
            })
        })
}
Go()
var Times = setInterval(function(){
    if (Bumps == Bump){
        clearInterval(Times)
    }
    Go()
    Bumps++
    whitespace_chars += ' ';
},40000)
```

There's a possibility that the website will trim the post body.  So keep that in mind.

*Disclaimer: I didn't test it, I hope it works.*